# How to find out how much ram a computer has in VB.net

Tags: .net, vb.net, ram

How would you work out the amount of ram that is in the computer

Comment: If this isn't a dupe, I'll eat my hat! Kuzon: did you try searching  before you posted?

Comment: Keyword/phrase/technology: [WMI: Windows Management Instrumentation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Management_Instrumentation). The -1 is for "no prior research".

Comment: @Mitch Yes, But all I could find was about how much ram is on your computer not how to find it in vb.net

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use the following:

```
Dim ram As ULong = My.Computer.Info.TotalPhysicalMemory
```

Comment: Strictly speaking that's the amount of RAM available to the OS. (Eg. consider 32bit Windows with 4GB fitted is likely only to have 3GB usable.)

Comment: OK sweet, exactly what i need :)