# How to get full info of the installed ram in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, basic

I am trying to find  the following information about my installed ram using vb.net 2017

[image]

Comment: https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=.NET+get+installed+RAM&oq=.NET+get+installed+RAM&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i60.2615j0j4&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8 . So many existing answers. What did you research? What did you try? We're not a free human search engine. Some of the answers are C# but a converter will change them to VB.NET in a few seconds. The library calls will be the same since it's all .NET.

Comment: Exact duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6805497/how-to-find-out-how-much-ram-a-computer-has-in-vb-net?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to find out how much ram a computer has in VB.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6805497/how-to-find-out-how-much-ram-a-computer-has-in-vb-net)

Answer (score 1):

```
 Dim ram As ULong = My.Computer.Info.TotalPhysicalMemory
```

By the rules, I should comment the code above, but really it's plain english...